# Speedup cython dictionary counter

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, cython

I wrote a simple cython script to optimize the collections.Counter of a dictionary counter and the python zip implementation (the main input is a list of tuples). Is there a way to speed it up?

```
%%cython --annotate
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def uniqueCounterListCython(list x not None):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i,n  

    n = len(x)    
    dx = defaultdict(int)
    for i from 0 <= i < n:
        dx[x[i]] += 1
    return dx


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def zipCython(np.ndarray[long,ndim=1] x1 not None, np.ndarray[long,ndim=1] x2 not None):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i,n

    n = x1.shape[0]
    l=[]
    for i from 0 <= i < n:
        l.append(((x1[i],x2[i])))
    return l
```

Sample input -

```
uniqueCounterListCython(zipCython(np.random.randint(0,3,200000),np.random.randint(0,3,200000)))
```

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

EDIT:
Found a kind of trivial way to speed things up - just merge the two functions:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def uniqueCounterListCythonWithZip(np.ndarray[long,ndim=1] x1 not None, np.ndarray[long,ndim=1] x2 not None):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i,n  

    n = x1.shape[0]    
    dx = defaultdict(int)
    for i from 0 <= i < n:
        dx[((x1[i],x2[i]))] += 1
    return dx
```

Any more suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Could you please run a profiler on your code to see what's slow? See the [Cython profiling tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/profiling_tutorial.html). Thanks!

Comment: I've added a profiling snapshot

Comment: this is not really useful, you forgot `# cython: profile=True` as explained in the tutorial. We want to know how much time is spent in functions called by Cython code. Thanks.

Comment: I've followed the tutorial and inserted # cython: profile=True  . What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure. It's no longer "magic" so maybe you can't get much better results than that. Is it still too slow for your needs?

Comment: Yes - it is still too slow..

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give us much context for this problem, so it's unclear to me exactly what you are trying to achieve. But in your example, you have a pair of NumPy arrays containing integers in the range 0–2, and you seem to want to count the number of occurrences of each pair of values.

So I suggest encoding pairs of integers in the range 0–2 into a single integer in the range 0–8, using [`numpy.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to do the counting, and then using [`numpy.reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) to decode the result, like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x, y = np.random.randint(0,3,200000), np.random.randint(0,3,200000)
>>> counts = np.bincount(x * 3 + y).reshape((3, 3))
>>> counts
array([[22282, 22093, 22247],
       [22084, 22295, 22396],
       [22012, 22243, 22348]])
```

A quick check that I got the encoding/decoding right:

```
>>> counts[0,2] == np.count_nonzero((x == 0) & (y == 2))
True
```

This runs much faster than the code in your question (assuming I have interpreted your profile screenshots correctly):

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:np.bincount(x * 3 + y).reshape((3, 3)), number=1000)
2.7519797360000666
```

Comment: Sorry for not properly defining the problem. This was the exact intention. Thank you!